# Can I force a scrollbar on a scrollable element in iOS 5+?

Tags: ios, css, safari

I'm using overflow: scroll; on a page that will be visible to mobile and desktop visitors, and it's working nicely. However there's no scrollbar on the scrollable element, so the user may not even realize that they should scroll.

Take this html for example:

```
<p style="height: 200px; width: 50%; margin-left: 25%; border: 1px solid #ccc; overflow: scroll;"> asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf  </p>
```

Here's a jsFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/tfQDB/

The element is perfectly scrollable but there's no visual indicator, even when scrolling. Do I have to put some images to indicate to the user that scrolling is possible, or is there a way to force iOS to show it's own scrollbar?

Comment: I see a vertical scroll... there's no content which extends past the block element horizontally so the scroll shows, but there's nothing to scroll to. If there's content to scroll to, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/tfQDB/1/

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512885/how-do-i-get-scrollbars-to-show-in-mobile-safari

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9275641/937084) may help

Comment: @Scott were you using an iOS 5+ device? When I view your link in a desktop browser I see scrollbars just fine, but when I view it on my iPad running iOS 5.0 I see no scrollbars. On my iPod running iOS 6.0 I also see no scrollbars.

Comment: @mdmullinax it is similar but that question was asked before iOS 5, I thought this was worth a separate question since iOS 5 did fix the two-finger scrolling issue which was a huge problem, so my issue here is specifically about scrollbars on iOS 5+

Comment: @Nick that's great, thanks, I hadn't seen that question! I updated the fiddle and it works perfectly on my iPad and iPod http://jsfiddle.net/tfQDB/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the scroll bar with CSS overflow on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845445/how-to-get-the-scroll-bar-with-css-overflow-on-ios)