# Jquery UI Accordion - no vertical scrollbar inside a pane content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-accordion, pane

I use a JQuery UI Dialog with an accordion and now I'm trying to show a vertical scrollbar on with ajax loaded content inside a pane. The problem is, that the scrollbar is not appearing on an Ipad. The problem exists only on IOS-Systems (Android not tested).

Here is the initialization part of the accordion:

```
var uiAccIcons = { header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e"
                 , headerSelected: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s" };

$("#uiAccordion").accordion({
   autoHeight: true,
   icons: uiAccIcons           
 });
```

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512885/how-do-i-get-scrollbars-to-show-in-mobile-safari) or [maybe this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818466/mac-os-x-lion-scrollbars-and-website-usability/9275641#9275641)

Comment: Thank you Zeaklous for your hint, I found the (CSS-)solution:

`::-webkit-scrollbar {
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 8px;    /* for vertical scrollbars */
height: 8px;    /* for horizontal scrollbars */
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border-radius:4px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
border-radius:4px;
}`